# How to mock local variables using mockito or powermock

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, junit4, powermock

I have scenario like this

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(getFileAsStream(resourceResolver, iconpath));
                BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
```

I have mocked till this point

```
getFileAsStream(resourceResolver, iconpath)
```

now I am getting one reader

```
 BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
```

but when I execute this line I get null and not able to move forward

```
  while ((iconEntry = bReader.readLine()) != null)
```

Please tell me how can I mock this. 
Please note I cannot change my main code therefore the solution present on Mockito docs is not valid in my case

Test code

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ FrameworkUtil.class, LoggerFactory.class })
public class IconPreviewServletTest {
    private IconPreviewServlet iconPreviewServlet;
    private SlingHttpServletRequest request;
    private SlingHttpServletResponse response;
    private Bundle bundle;
    private BundleContext bundleContext;
    private ServiceReference factoryRef;
    private CommonService resolverFactory;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private ResourceResolver resourceResolver;
    private Resource resource;
    private Node node;
    private Node jcrContent;
    private javax.jcr.Property property;
    private Binary binary;
    private InputStream stream;
    private InputStreamReader inputReader;
    private BufferedReader reader;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws IOException, PathNotFoundException,
            RepositoryException {
        init();
    }

    private void init() throws IOException, PathNotFoundException,
            RepositoryException {

        request = mock(SlingHttpServletRequest.class);
        response = mock(SlingHttpServletResponse.class);
        bundleContext = mock(BundleContext.class);
        factoryRef = mock(ServiceReference.class);
        resolverFactory = mock(CommonService.class);
        out = mock(PrintWriter.class);
        resourceResolver = mock(ResourceResolver.class);
        resource = mock(Resource.class);
        node = mock(Node.class);
        jcrContent = mock(Node.class);
        property = mock(Property.class);
        binary = mock(Binary.class);
        stream=IOUtils.toInputStream("some test data for my input stream");



        reader = mock(BufferedReader.class);

        inputReader=mock(InputStreamReader.class);

        bundle = mock(Bundle.class);
        mockStatic(FrameworkUtil.class);
        mockStatic(LoggerFactory.class);

        Logger log = mock(Logger.class);

        when(LoggerFactory.getLogger(IconPreviewServlet.class)).thenReturn(log);
        when(FrameworkUtil.getBundle(CommonService.class)).thenReturn(bundle);
        when(bundle.getBundleContext()).thenReturn(bundleContext);
        when(bundleContext.getServiceReference(CommonService.class.getName()))
                .thenReturn(factoryRef);
        when(bundleContext.getService(factoryRef)).thenReturn(resolverFactory);
        when(request.getParameter("category")).thenReturn("category");
        when(request.getParameter("query")).thenReturn("query");
        when(response.getWriter()).thenReturn(out);
        when(request.getResourceResolver()).thenReturn(resourceResolver);
        when(
                resourceResolver
                        .getResource("/etc/designs/resmed/icons/category/icons.txt"))
                .thenReturn(resource);
        when(resource.adaptTo(Node.class)).thenReturn(node);
        when(node.getNode("jcr:content")).thenReturn(jcrContent);
        when(jcrContent.getProperty("jcr:data")).thenReturn(property);
        when(property.getBinary()).thenReturn(binary);
        when(binary.getStream()).thenReturn(stream);

    }
```

Comment: could you show the test code ?

Comment: @TienNguyen test code added

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To make this work, you need to use Powermockito to intercept the constructor calls (new InputStreamReader(...), new BufferedReader(...)) so that your mocks get returned. An example is below. In your case, just intercepting the new BufferedReader call may be enough.

Assume the following is the code you want to test:

```
package test;

import java.io.*;

public class SUT {

    public String doSomething() throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader reader =
                new InputStreamReader(getFileAsStream(null, null));
        BufferedReader bReader =
                new BufferedReader(reader);

        return bReader.readLine();
    }

    private InputStream getFileAsStream(Object resourceResolver, Object iconPath)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream("".getBytes());
    }
}
```

The following test code is an example of how to intercept the constructor calls:

```
package test;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.doReturn;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ SUT.class })
public class SUTTest {

    @Test
    public void doSomethingReturnsValueFromBufferedReader() throws Exception {
        // Arrange
        SUT sut = new SUT();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReaderMock = mock(InputStreamReader.class);
        BufferedReader bufferedReaderMock = mock(BufferedReader.class);

        // Set your mocks up to be returned when the new ...Reader calls 
        // are executed in sut.doSomething()
        PowerMockito.whenNew(InputStreamReader.class).
                     withAnyArguments().thenReturn(inputStreamReaderMock);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(BufferedReader.class).
                     withArguments(inputStreamReaderMock).
                     thenReturn(bufferedReaderMock);

        // Set the value you want bReader.readLine() to return 
        // when sut.doSomething() executes
        final String bufferedReaderReturnValue = "myValue";
        doReturn(bufferedReaderReturnValue).when(bufferedReaderMock).readLine();

        // Act
        String result = sut.doSomething();

        // Assert
        assertEquals(bufferedReaderReturnValue, result);
    }
}
```

This hopefully helps you in your immediate problem. However, it seems to me that what you're creating will be a very slow, confusing and brittle test. Right now, you're mocking so much that it makes very hard to determine what you're actually trying to test.

The high amount of mocking probably indicates that the design of the code you're testing would need some work to improve testability. If you can't touch the code, then you can't - but try to make your test more readable and intuitive ("When this method is invoked, this thing should happen, because...").

Answer (score 1):

to make this line work:

```
 while ((iconEntry = bReader.readLine()) != null)
```

you must determine how many lines you want to read and add this to your test code:

```
when(bReader.readLine()).thenReturn("line number one").thenReturn("line number two");
```

Comment: in my case bReader is an original object so how can I call when on it.
If i try to do so I get exception. Saying that you are calling when on a non mocked object

Comment: you have to mock bReader also, but you already put it at your test code: "reader = mock(BufferedReader.class);" so just use it to call readLine() function