# Injection testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, http-get

In Java, I have some code which gets some data from a server via HttpGet/HttpResponse, then convert the HttpResponse to a string.  It works like a charm.

I am trying to write good unit tests on these two separate functions because I have found a use case in determining whether the HttpGet fails and what the server reply code is, as well as if the transformation from the HttpResponse to a string fails for whatever reason.  The HttpResponse Entity toString extraction may fail because this process takes around a half hour to complete.  Its a slow box, and its a lot of data.

My question is how one may "fake" a HttpResponse object containing an entity that is comprised of a local file in a resource bundle.  Apparently, I can't use file:/// as it doesn't look like its supported with HttpGet(1);

Again, my code has these two functions:

```
public HttpResponse requestData(){
    String urlLocation = extStrings.getString("urlLocation");  <--- I need to support local file here 
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpGet = new HttpGet(urlLocation);
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        logger.info("Calling the URL connection");
        response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.error("Could not start connection with the URL: " + urlLocation);
        httpGet.releaseConnection();
    }
    if(statusCode != 200){
       logger.error("Server reply code is not 200 as desired.  Instead it is: " + statusCode);
       System.exit(0);
    }
    return response; 
}

public String responseData(response){
    if(response == null){ return null; }
    HttpEntity entity;
    String result = "";
    logger.info("Getting the entity of the URL response");
    entity = response.getEntity();
    try {
        logger.info("Converting the page into a string, this takes too long");
        result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        logger.info("Consuming the entity");
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.error("Problem with entity conversion");
    }
    logger.info("Releasing the connection");
    httpGet.releaseConnection();
    return result;
}
```

In main; responseData(requestData());

Answer (score 1):

You can try using PowerMockito to intercept the constructor call. new DefaultHttpClient() in your case. And then use mocked object to return your "fake" HttpResponse.
Check the example here:

[How to mock local variables using mockito or powermock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20014547/how-to-mock-local-variables-using-mockito-or-powermock)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to inject the HttpClient to your class.

```
public class YourClass {
  private final HttpClient client;

  public YourClass(HttpClient client) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  ...
}
```

Then you can mock the HttpClient and gain control of the response. (I use Mockito here.)

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {
  HttpClient client = mock(HttpClient.class);
  when(client.execute(any(HttpResponse.class)).thenReturn(createTheResponse());
  YourClass object = new YourClass(client);
  ...
}
```

The `HttpResponse` can itself be a mock/stub.

Comment: What about if I wanted to save the class as a serialized file or something so my test case can just read from a file?

Comment: In the event that the request to get the response fails, I still would like to test to see if the method that handles the response is functioning correctly

Comment: You can mock a failing response, too: doThrow(new IOException()).when(client).execute(any(HttpResponse.class)

Comment: "save the class as a serialized file"??? Do you mean saving a serialized object? Which class?