# How to mock a local static variable?

Tags: java

My class uses a static local variable of `org.slf4j.Logger`. Is there some clever way of replacing this with a mock object for my testing? I'm thinking my best option is for `MyClass` to expose a setter?

Also, how can I mock the Logger object? I'd like to mock it such that when `LOGGER.error(string, exception)` is called I'd like to validate the error String.

```
public class MyClass {
  private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

Comment: You may mock the logger and do what you're explaining, but that seems overkill and a bad practice to follow. Instead, you should write your tests to validate results on variables and/or if an exception was thrown rather than this.

Comment: @DavidHaim it's a variable declared `static` and it's *local* for the class...

Comment: so it's just "static"

Comment: Why not just mock/configure the underlying loggers/log system?

Comment: Maybe the answer of this question helps you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385161/powermock-testing-set-static-field-of-class

Comment: ... or another along these lines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20014547/how-to-mock-local-variables-using-mockito-or-powermock

Comment: just remove `private` and `final` :) no big deal, they just try to scare us.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Why is this bad practice? Is there no value in asserting the actual log message is as expected?

Comment: Because that's fragile and there may be tons of log messages. I recommend you to read more about how to write good unit tests.